# SQL Query - Multiple different sums in a single column

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, row

I want to create an SQL Query that will be saved as a stored procedure, which is then called by an XML script. It must then be in a certain format, and have only one value column.

I need to display the outcome of three different sums in a single column, in separate rows. I haven't worked out how this is possible, and currently the values are being output to three different 'Value' columns.

The purpose of the query is to display the size of databases on an SQL server with a certain name.

The query is currently querying an SQL Server, and targeting databases containing "@name" in their name. It is displaying the total size of those databases including their log files, and including offline databases. I had it displaying the total size, but I also want to show the total size of database files and log files separately, in different rows, in the same column.

Here is my query:

```
declare
    @name NVARCHAR(20)
set
    @name = 'H3'

select
    @name as Channel,
    sum((a.size*8)/1024) Value,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'ROWS' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'LOG' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value,
    '1' as IsInt,
    'MB' as Unit
from 
    sys.databases b
    left join sys.master_files a
        on b.database_id = a.database_id

where 
    b.name like '%'+@name+'%'
```

The output currently looks like:

```
Channel   Value    Value   Value  IsInt  Unit
--------- -------  ------- ------ ------ ------
H3        140091   134737  5354   1      MB
```

I want it to display:

```
Channel   Value   IsInt  Unit
--------- ------- ------ ------
H3        140091  1      MB
H3        134737  1      MB
H3        5354    1      MB
```

I would appreciate any help, as I am really stuck on this one.
I am very new to SQL, so the answer may be obvious.

This is in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Will the result set always have a single record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using a UNION ALL and split your query to 3 different queries will solve your problem?

```
declare @name NVARCHAR(20)
set   @name = 'H3'

select
@name as Channel,
sum((a.size*8)/1024) Value,
'1' as IsInt,
'MB' as Unit
from 
sys.databases b
left join sys.master_files a on b.database_id = a.database_id

where 
b.name like '%'+@name+'%'

UNION ALL

select
@name as Channel,
SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'ROWS' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value,
'1' as IsInt,
'MB' as Unit
from 
sys.databases b
left join sys.master_files a on b.database_id = a.database_id

where 
b.name like '%'+@name+'%'

UNION ALL

select
@name as Channel,
SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'LOG' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value,
'1' as IsInt,
'MB' as Unit
from 
sys.databases b
left join sys.master_files a on b.database_id = a.database_id

where 
b.name like '%'+@name+'%'
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly, I just had to declare and set '@name' at the start. I had never heard of 'UNION ALL' before, but it does the job. Does it essentially just join 3 output tables, or join 3 select statements and create a table?

Comment: @Harnell Glad it worked. UNION ALL simply combines the results of the SELECT statements. Please be aware, that each query have to have the same number of columns to use UNION ALL. There are also UNION, which is similar, but filters out duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CTE` to make the result and combine using `UNION ALL`.

```
declare @name NVARCHAR(20)
set @name = 'H3'

;with cte_1
as
(select
    @name as Channel,
    sum((a.size*8)/1024) Value1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'ROWS' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'LOG' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value3,
    '1' as IsInt,
    'MB' as Unit
from 
    sys.databases b
    left join sys.master_files a
        on b.database_id = a.database_id
where 
    b.name like '%'+@name+'%')
SELECT Channel,Value1 Value,IsInt,Unit
FROM cte_1
UNION ALL
SELECT Channel,Value2,IsInt,Unit
FROM cte_1
UNION ALL
SELECT Channel,Value3,IsInt,Unit
FROM cte_1
```

Comment: I think the results should be ordered.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  As per the given sample, Output only needs to convert the column values to Rows.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to unpivot your result. There are different ways to do that. You can use the most common ways: the `UNION ALL` method, or the `UNPIVOT` method. However, there is another method that is usually faster than these two, the `CROSS APPLY` method:

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(20)
SET @name = 'H3';

WITH Cte(Channel, TotalValue, RowsValue, LogsValue, IsInt, Unit) AS(
    SELECT
        @name AS Channel,
        SUM((a.size * 8) / 1024) Value,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc LIKE 'ROWS' THEN (a.size * 8) / 1024 ELSE 0 END) AS Value,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc LIKE 'LOG' THEN (a.size * 8) / 1024 ELSE 0 END) AS Value,
        '1' AS IsInt,
        'MB' AS Unit
    FROM sys.databases b
    LEFT JOIN sys.master_files a
        ON b.database_id = a.database_id

    WHERE b.name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
)
SELECT
    c.Channel,
    t.value,
    c.IsInt,
    c.Unit
FROM Cte c
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    (c.TotalValue), (c.RowsValue), (c.LogsValue)
) t(value)
```

Here is Dwain Camp's article comparing the different ways to unpivot:

- [An Alternative (Better?) Method to UNPIVOT (SQL Spackle)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/)

---

You could easily add another column in the `VALUES` to allow for more descriptive `Channel`:

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(20)
SET @name = 'H3';

WITH Cte(Channel, TotalValue, RowsValue, LogsValue, IsInt, Unit) AS(
    SELECT
        @name AS Channel,
        SUM((a.size * 8) / 1024) Value,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc LIKE 'ROWS' THEN (a.size * 8) / 1024 ELSE 0 END) AS Value,
        SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc LIKE 'LOG' THEN (a.size * 8) / 1024 ELSE 0 END) AS Value,
        '1' AS IsInt,
        'MB' AS Unit
    FROM sys.databases b
    LEFT JOIN sys.master_files a
        ON b.database_id = a.database_id

    WHERE b.name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
)
SELECT
    c.Channel + ' ' + name AS Channel,
    t.value,
    c.IsInt,
    c.Unit
FROM Cte c
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('Total', c.TotalValue), 
    ('Rows', c.RowsValue), 
    ('Logs', c.LogsValue)
) t(name, value)
```

Comment: This method works too, thanks. I guess I should use it if it is faster than UNION ALL?

Comment: Yes, as per the article, it performs better than the two.

Comment: With 'UNION ALL', I have changed the name in the channel column to 'H3 Total', 'H3 Databases', 'H3 Log Files'.                                                            I can do this easily because there are 3 different select statements, so I can just edit to "@name + ' Databases' as Channel,". How can I do this using cross apply?

Comment: @Harnell See my updated answer. Adding a column in the `VALUES` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot / Unpivot :

```
            declare
                @name NVARCHAR(20)
            set
                @name = 'H3'

                select Channel , Value ,IsInt ,Unit from 
                            (
            select
                @name as Channel,
                sum((a.size*8)/1024) Value0,
                SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'ROWS' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value1,
                SUM(CASE WHEN type_desc like 'LOG' THEN (a.size*8)/1024 ELSE 0 END) Value2,
                '1' as IsInt,
                'MB' as Unit             
                from 
                sys.databases b
                left join sys.master_files a
                on b.database_id = a.database_id
                where b.name like '%'+@name+'%'

                            ) as xx
                               unpivot
                               (
                Value for col in (Value0,Value1,value2)
            )aaa
```

Please let us know if you have any concenrs